# Get element behind another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently trying to create my own drag and drop function in javascript (with events listeners) and i'm facing one problem : when I start dragging my element, I can't get to know where I am since the element im dragging is in front of my cursor.

I'd like to know if it's possible to get the position of my cursor without being affected by the element im dragging.

Note : **I can't use Jquery to acheive this**

Thanks,

Edit : My code

```
var i = 0;
window.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
var leftMarg = document.getElementById('moving').offsetWidth / 2;
var topMarg = document.getElementById('moving').offsetHeight / 2;

function stopDrag(e) {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', dragging);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', grabbing);
}

function startDrag() {
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', grabbing);
}

function grabbing(e) {
    for (let i = 1; i < document.getElementById("test").children.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById("test").children[i].contains(e.target)) {
            document.getElementById("moving").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("moving").innerText = e.target.innerText;
            window.removeEventListener('mousemove', grabbing);
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', dragging);
        }
    }
}

function dragging(e) {
    document.getElementById("moving").style.left = (e.x - leftMarg) + "px";
    document.getElementById("moving").style.top = (e.y - topMarg) + "px";
}
```

Comment: add code which you have do for it

Comment: Welcome to [https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/)
! At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when listening to the onmousemove event you can get the mouse position with event.clientX/Y. Examples are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmousemove (contains also Drag and Drop example) and here: https://jsfiddle.net/qf4atst5/

You need to calculate clientX/Y - element's left/topOffset to get the mouse position relative to your element.:

```
element.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    xpos = e.clientX - e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    ypos = e.clientY - e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    element.innerText = "x=" + xpos + ", y=" + ypos;
});
```

No jQuery required

PS: To get your mouse position remove the `e.target.getBoundingClientRect().*`

Comment: Thanks, thats the best I could hope for, I should be able now to do what I want.